# how to update Canopy's Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, canopy

```
from pandas_datareader import data as webdata
mydata = webdata.DataReader("GDPMCA1", "fred")
```

produces the `InsecurePlatformWarning` as described at https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.  So I need to update my python 2.7 (Win 64).  This used to be no problem (just install over the old), but I've switched to using the Canopy Python distribution.  How best to proceed?  Does Canopy provide an easy way to update to its latest supported Python 2.7.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to uninstall & reinstall, but if you want you can leave your package set untouched. See this article: https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469570-Canopy-shows-no-updates-available-reinstalling-from-the-website